# How do I get just the filename from lsof?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I want to use **lsof** to create a list of open files in a folder.  I'm using macOS, but understand this is common to *nix.

In **man lsof**, it seems the the -Fn option is closest to what I want, but I can't get further than that. I'm piping to cut to get to just the filename.  So this is the command I'm using:

`$ lsof -Fn dir1 | cut -c2-`

I'm expecting

```
dir1/file1.txt
```

I'm getting

```
32783
34
dir1/file1.txt
32785
3
dir1/.DS_Store
```

Comment: Good that you have shown your efforts in your post, it is always recommended to post sample of input and expected output too in your post, to get clear picture of your question.

Comment: may be `lsof |grep -oP '/.*'` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following(since no samples were posted so tested in my test box only).

```
lsof  | awk 'match($0,/\/([^ ])*|\/([^$])*/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Since OP need not to have files with DOT in their names(basically hidden ones I think) then one could try following.

```
lsof  | 
awk '
FNR>1 && match($0,/\/.*/){
   val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
   if(val !~ /\/\./){
     print val
   }
   val=""
}'
```

Comment: Thank you, that does the trick. I thought there would be a way to do it with the options on lsof.  I'll have a play around to understand that regex.  Is there a way to exclude the dot files?

Comment: @RedZebra, sure, I will add some explanation in my post in few mins too. Related to DOT files if you could post an example I could tweak the code as per that then, let me know example.

Comment: Thank you. Output lines like this.  Usually .DS_Store.  `/testing?Dir2/.DS_Store`

Comment: @RedZebra, Sure, could you please try my EDIT command and let me know, since I don't have any hidden file coming in `lsof` so couldn't test it, let me know?

Comment: This works brilliantly in a shell script.  When I try to put it in perl `system()` command, there's all kinds of problems.  Any tips?

Comment: OK, so I've called the bash script from perl as a child process.  All's good.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this command:

```
lsof your_dir | awk '{print $9}'
```

Update:

```
lsof your_dir | awk '{for(i=9;i<=NF;++i)print $i}'
```

this will print column 9 to the end.

Comment: Thanks.  This looks good and should work well.  Problem is that some of the filenames have spaces in them, so it only selects the first word of the name.